# Get value of label when UIScrollview did stop scrolling animation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, ios5

I am developing an infinite horizontal scroll view to get month and year values for my app. I found a way for the infinite scrolling but I have no idea how to get the value of the label when scrolling did stop animating or dragging. 
 [image: I want to get the value of the march label when scrolling ends]

1. Is there any way to get the month value using my above component when scrolling did end animating/ dragging or do I need to change my component?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

got a solution

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{

//some logics go here..........

    CGPoint point = scrollView.center; 

        for (UIView *myView in scrollView.subviews)
        {

            if(CGPointEqualToPoint(myView.center, point) == YES )
            {
                   if([myView isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) 
                  {
                    UILabel *label = (UILabel *)myView;
                    NSLog(@"Month is %@", label.text);
                  }
            }
        }
}
```

the above code will return the label at the center of the scroll view.

Comment: and in case there is another subview having the same center point, this code will not work and may also crash at NSLog statement.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your scrollView implementation, in general you can get subview at the center point with

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

Check the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html) for details. Ideally your scrollView knows which view is moved to the center and it is able to return it by some of your custom methods.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code to retrieve subviews from main view.

**-In your scroll delegate scrolldidEnd method:**

```
UIView v = nil;
for(v in yourscroll.subviews){
 if ([v isKindOfClass:UILabel]){
      UILabel * lbl = v(UILabel *);
     if (lbl.tag == yourSelectedLabelTag){
       NSLog(lbl.text);
             }
      }
}
```

Note: your must create **tag** with label view in scrollview.

Comment: hey my question is how can I get the "yourSelectedLabelTag" when scrolling did end....